# Name for an expectation of this form $\mathbb{E}X 1_{A}$?

Tags: probability, references, expected-value, terminology

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space; let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable; let $A \in \mathscr{F}$; let $1_{A}$ be the indicator function of $A$. Now is there an established (in some sense) term for the expectation $\mathbb{E}X1_{A}$? A phrase like "the mean of $X$ over $A$" seems a little bit too cumbersome. I am after something short but indicative like "partial mean" (mind not this term, I coined which to help narrow down the scope of search.).

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, you are dancing around the conditional expectation, though it's not quite what you're looking for. I wanted to make this a comment but it came in a bit too long.

Recall $\mathbb{E}X = \int_\Omega X d\mathbb{P}$. Let $\mathscr{A}\subseteq \mathscr{F}$ be a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathscr{F}$ and let $A \in \mathscr{A}$. We know the following,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X\mid A) &= \frac{ \int_A X d\mathbb{P}}{\int_\Omega 1_Ad\mathbb{P}} \\
&= \frac{ \int_\Omega X1_A d\mathbb{P}}{\int_\Omega 1_Ad\mathbb{P}} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}X1_A}{\mathbb{P}A} 
\end{align*}

So that your quantity of interest is $\mathbb{E}X1_A = \mathbb{E}(X\mid A) {\mathbb{P}A}  $. I suppose this doesn't answer your question as I don't provide a name for it, but hopefully searching down the path of conditional expectations, or the law of total expectations might come up with something. I believe I have seen it referred to as the **local average**,but I can't seem to remember where.